# Laravel 5.1 views not found and got error 404 on site navigation

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm trying to write a project with this framework. But when I upload my site in my shared host, I got error 404 in all of the site links, except site home page. While the site works fine in xampp.

My code:

**html**:

```
      <li>
          <a href="soon">
              آرشیو مقاله
          </a>
      </li>

     <li>
          <a href="contact">
              ارتباط با ما
          </a>
      </li>

      <li>
          <a href="about">
              درباره ما
          </a>
       </li>
```

**Routes.php**:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('home');
});

Route::get('/soon', 'NavigationController@soon');
Route::get('/about', function () {
     return View::make('about');
});
Route::get('/contact', function () {
     echo 'contact ';
});
```

**NavigationController.php** :

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 class NavigationController extends Controller
 {
    function soon(){
       return view('soon');
    }
 }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: make sure your `<base>` has  `href`  set to your site's root

Answer (score 0):

Possible your shared hoster does not support mod_rewrite or has not activated the extension for your webspace?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @some-non-descript-user, let it be. this user does not have enough rep to actually comment.

Comment: sorry was late for me yesterday so it seems i did not read correctly.